# What is `COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE`

Tags: android, sqlite

I was going through the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow) of how to do database operations on Android using SqlLite. In the "Put information into database" section the insert() method takes 3 parameters

1) Table Name
2) .COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE
3) values

The documentation below it says `'COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE' the second argument provides the name of a column in which the framework can insert NULL in the event that the ContentValues is empty (if you instead set this to "null", then the framework will not insert a row when there are no values).`

But i do not have any field in FeedEntry class with a value as 'COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE'. I do not understand from where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [actual documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) for the `insert()` method:

> *nullColumnHack*
>   optional; may be `null`. SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your provided `values` is empty, no column names are known and an empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the `nullColumnHack` parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL into in the case where your `values` is empty.

If it makes sense to have a completely empty row in the database, just use some column name of the table. Otherwise, use `null`.

Comment: Hey from what I understand (Correct me if I am wrong)- if my values object is empty and i provide null as a second parameter data will not get inserted ?

Comment: Yes. But in most apps, there are no empty `ContentValues` objects.